# How to show the form based on subcategory

Tags: php

[image]
sub_cat table like BTech Tuition (Chemical Engineering),BTech Tuition (Civil Engineering).In this table you see pid is the parent_cat primarykey and cid is the child_cat table primary key the two id are passing to sub_cat .

Here is my code for showing form based on category id:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   $category=$_POST['category'];
   $query=mysql_query("select * from child_cat c where c.cid='".$category."'");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
  {
    $cid=$row['cid'];
    $ch_cat=$row['ch_cat'];
  }
}
$sqlsubject=mysql_query("select * from sub_cat c where c.cid='".$cid."'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlsubject))
{
?>
<input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value=<?php echo $row['sub_cat'];?>>        
<?php echo $row['sub_cat'];?><br/>
<?php
}
?>
```

Myquestion is:
1.How do i separate the form based on cid in sub_Cat table.
This form is for class I_V,classI-VIII, Class IX-X. if they select classI_V I want to show this form. 
select medium:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="regional[]" id="hind" value="hindi" required>Hindi
<input type="checkbox" name="regional[]" id="eng" value="english">English
<input type="checkbox" name="regional[]" id="reg" value="regional">Regional Language
```

2.for btech this  select medium is not required.

Comment: Mention sample data of `parent_cat` and `child_cat` tables.

Comment: http://sql13.000webhost.com/phpMyAdmin/index.php?db=a2386332_ashish&table=parent_cat&lang=en-utf-8&token=b3f11b3508aa13f3e248d0e75a2972b2  username is:a2386332_ashish and password is:subject123

Comment: did you understand my backend. tell me otherwise i will explain to you